# How to express a continuous signal with basic functions

Tags: signal-processing

My goal is to express this continuous signal by using $u(t)$ (unit step) and $r(t)$ (unit ramp)basic functions

- $u(t)$

[image]

- $r(t)$

[image]

- The signal

[image]

So i would say that $x(t) = u(t) - r(t-1)$

Although my calculation is wrong, i have to add $+r(t-2)$ to $x(t)$ i can not quite understand why.

Why the correct answer is $x(t) =  u(t) - r(t-1) + r(t-2)$  ?

**Note:**  I'm new with with this kind of mathematics and expressions , any edit would be appriciated!

Comment: I guess $r(t) = t$ for $t\ge 0$? What do you mean by "express this continuous signal" - what is this signal? Is it the combined red and blue one between 0 and 2??

Comment: this is the $x(t)$ and i have to express it with $u(t)$ and $r(t)$ ,  $r(t) = t$ for $t>0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signal vanishes after t = 2.

To add the upward function $r(t-2)$ is to compensate, or neutralize, the downward signal $-r(t-1)$ for t > 2. Otherwise, the signal would last forever.